# RxSwift: observe an array stored in UserDefaults

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults, rx-swift

I am trying to observe my `UserDefaults` to monitor changes to `locations`, which is an array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
extension UserDefaults {

    var ob: Observable<[CLLocationCoordinate2D]> {
        return self.rx.observe(Array.self, "locations")
    }

}
```

But I get this error:

```
no 'observe' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'Observable<[CLLocationCoordinate2D]>' (aka 'Observable<Array<CLLocationCoordinate2D>>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`observe` will return an `Observable` of an optional element: `Observable<[CLLocationCoordinate2D]?>`

It's not a very good error. It would have been more helpful if it had said what type it **was** seeing you trying to return, instead of just what it expected.

One way you could have seen this is by creating a variable and then returning that instead.

```
var ob: Observable<[CLLocationCoordinate2D]> {
    let a = self.rx.observe(Array<CLLocationCoordinate2D>.self, "locations")
    return a
}
```

You would have been able to see what type `a` is (`Observable<[CLLocationCoordinate2D]?>`), and also would have gotten a better error message:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'Observable<[CLLocationCoordinate2D]?>' (aka 'Observable<Optional<Array<CLLocationCoordinate2D>>>') to return type 'Observable<[CLLocationCoordinate2D]>' (aka 'Observable<Array<CLLocationCoordinate2D>>')
```

So, correcting that mistake, your code should look like this:

```
var ob: Observable<[CLLocationCoordinate2D]?> {
    return self.rx.observe(Array.self, "locations")
}
```

Although I would suggest you don't rely on type inference and instead be explicit about the array's element type. Swift has a hard enough time as it is:

```
var ob: Observable<[CLLocationCoordinate2D]?> {
    return self.rx.observe(Array<CLLocationCoordinate2D>.self, "locations")
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I can `rx.observe` a non-Array type. I can get value of the Array type using just `array:forKey`, but I can't `rx.observe` an Array type. Always returns `nil` (and the value for the key is definitely there as it's returned by `array:forKey`).